# Angular - Bind two properties to one input field and pass other property as validation parameter

Tags: angular

I have a ts file bound to the template. Now in that template there is an input tag which is bound to one property. Now I want to do validation on that property in such a way that I need to compare the value of this property to another property within same model.

Trying several things like creating custom directive and attribute for a place holder to bind the second property but this does not get updated to the back ts file.

```
//property2 used from model to compare with value in validation of property1
function SomeValidation(model: Model1): ValidatorFn {

        return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
            if (control.value !== undefined && (isNaN(control.value) || control.value >= model.property2)) {
                return { 'maxReservedBalance': true };
            }
            return null;
        };

}

@Component({
    selector: 'area1',
    templateUrl: 'abc.html',
  ...
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, ValueDirectives]
})

export class TabComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() model: Model1;  


 property1: Control;
 property2: Control; 

 constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {    

///want to set this model1      
        property1: = new Control('', SomeValidation(this.model));   
}
```

Comment: add some code here what you have tried

Comment: @jitender Updated the code that I am trying

Comment: I referred you to one of my answers about that. Read carefully both answers though, this is very informational.